# 500 Internal Server Error Cron Job with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cron

I'm working on a cron job that adds a value to a database. I'm using Codeigniter. I'm testing the script using the terminal. It works while on my local machine (I'm using MAMP), but when I upload it to my server and run the script it give me the following error:
    Status: 500 Internal Server Error
    Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No matter what I do, it doesn't do anything different. What causes this and how can I fix it?

EDITED:

I'm using Codeigniter 3.0.3.

**Cron Controller**

```
class Cron extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('cron_m');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(!$this->input->is_cli_request())
        {
            echo "This script can only be accessed via the command line" . PHP_EOL;
            return;
        }

        $data = array('value' => 'test');
        $this->cron_m->save($data);
        echo 'saved!';

    }

}
```

**Frontend_Controller**

```
class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        
     }

    public function lock()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');        
        $this->load->model('user_m');   

        // Login check
        $exception_uris = array(
            'admin/user/login',
            'admin/user/logout'
        );

        if (in_array(uri_string(), $exception_uris) == FALSE)
        {
            if ($this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE)
            {
                $uri = $this->uri->uri_string();
                $this->session->set_tempdata('uri', $uri);

                redirect('admin/user/login');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**MY_Controller**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['errors'] = array();

    }

}
```

**Cron_m Model**

```
class Cron_m extends MY_Model {

    public $_table_name = 'CRON';
    protected $_order_by = 'id';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

**MY_Model**

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    public $_table_name = '';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
    protected $_order_by = 'order';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function save($data, $id = NULL)
    {

        //INSERT
        if ($id === NULL)
        {           
            !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        //UPDATE
        else
        {
            $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
            $id = $filter($id);
            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
            $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
        }

        return $id;

    }

}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets|uploads|podcast\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: what is the version of your CI?? add code as well

Comment: added my code and version

Comment: is there any session in this??

Comment: i mean to enter to cron controller, do u need any session?? like user has to logged in to use cron??

Comment: no, I was having issues with sessions due to the ip_address not being available when trying to enter into a database. So no session

Comment: have you follower naming styles of CI3??

Comment: to the best of my knowledge

Comment: Controller model n libraries names will start from capital letters...??

Comment: Yes, that is how they are named.

Comment: if u run cron controller directly for url, is it working??

Comment: yes, it runs with no problems

Comment: in live server or local server??

Comment: show the cron command.

Comment: php /home4/kottkea1/public_html/fallspointechurch/index.php cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using just the php command, but after searching I found this post - [CodeIgniter Cron Job through Cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558830/codeigniter-cron-job-through-cpanel). Instead of using php I'm now using php5-cli and it works like a champ.

```
php5-cli path/to/folder/index cron set_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly write a codeigniter function in a controller. Make sure it satisfies following criteria

- To access the codeigniter function no login should be there
- In function you should not use any session.

Then in cpanel of your server, you can set cron based on your requirement, either every minute, every hour, etc.

Also use `wget` ,

```
wget -T 0 -O path_to_a_text_file_where_cron_will_write_errors path_to_your_script_that_should_be_run_by_cron
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i'm getting a different error `wget -T 0 -O /home4/kottkea1/public_html/fallspointechurch/assets/errors.txt /home4/kottkea1/public_html/fallspointechurch/index.php cron
/home4/kottkea1/public_html/fallspointechurch/index.php: Scheme missing.
--2015-11-27 23:24:33--  http://cron/
Resolving cron... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “cron”`

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I just started trying out cron jobs a could of days ago so I have no idea what I'm doing :) and i know just enough about terminal commands to get me around

Comment: tried that it gives me the same error...could it have anything to do with how i am trying to access my controller. the codeigniter documentation said to run controllers is as follows: /index.php cron. Would that be why it's throwing an error. I can't access the controller directly.

Comment: after index.php, you have space??

Comment: remove space and add `/`

Comment: working my way through errors, haha - I'm now getting this error `/home4/kottkea1/public_html/fallspointechurch/index.php/cron: Scheme missing.`

Answer (score 0):

i think cron job will work only with core php code you have to make new file like cron.php and put this file in root directory and write your code in core php format and then save your cron job url on cpanel i think it will work 100 % cron job with ci doesn`t work because i have already face this issue please try this way